# Jil.DeserializationException : Error occurred building a deserializer in redis cache

Tags: c#, jil

I'm using Redis Cache using Stack Exchange library.

I used [cloudStructure](https://github.com/neuecc/CloudStructures) library to use Redis Dictionary and Redis List.

> Problem is when I try to retrieve values and if that model has a null
>    value for one list property it is throwing me below exception -
>
> Jil.DeserializationException : Error occurred building a deserializer
>   for TestMainClass: Expected a
>   parameterless constructor for
>   System.Collections.Generic.ICollection`1[TestChildClass]
>   ---- Jil.Common.ConstructionException : Expected a parameterless constructor for
>   System.Collections.Generic.ICollection`1[TestChildClass]

```
public class TestMainClass
    {
        public TestMainClass();
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<TestChildClass> Mydata { get; set; }
        public string Title { get; set; }
    }


      public class TestChildClass
    {
        public TestChildClass();
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Value { get; set; }
    }
```

Redis code for retrieve value:

```
RedisDictionary<int, TestMainClass> dictionary = 
new RedisDictionary<int, TestMainClass>("localhost", "mylocaldictionary");
var result = await dictionary.Get(121);
```

What If I could not able to convert ICollection < T > into List < T >?

Comment: Changing the tags, as this has nothing to do with redis or SE.Redis or caching, and everything to do with Jil

Comment: [Issue opened](https://github.com/kevin-montrose/Jil/issues/162) ; I'll take a look when I get a chance.

Comment: @Neo note that the issue above notes that it already works for `IList<T>`, if that is an option

Comment: This has now been fixed in `head` for Jil.  Will be in next release (so, anything > 2.11.0).

Comment: @MarcGravell Can you help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It might be a nice feature if the serialization library detected interfaces like `ICollection<T>` and `IList<T>` and implemented them with the concrete `List<T>` during deserialization, but ultimately: every feature needs to be thought of, considered (impact), designed, implemented, tested, documented and supported. It may be that the library author feels this is a great idea and should be implemented; it might not be high on the author's list, but they'd be more than happy to take a pull request; or there might be good reasons not to implement it.

In the interim, as a general rule that will solve virtually every serialization problem you will ever encounter with any library:

- the moment the library doesn't work perfectly with your domain model: stop serializing your domain model - use a DTO instead

By which, I mean: create a *separate* class or classes that are designed with the specific choice of serializer in mind. If it wants `List<T>`: then use `List<T>`. If it wants public fields:  use public fields. If it wants the types to be marked `[Serializable]`: mark the types `[Serializable]`. If it wants all type names to start with `SuperMagic`: then start the type name with `SuperMagic`. As soon as you divorce the domain model from the serialization model, *all the problems go away*. In addition: you can support *multiple* serializers in parallel, without getting into the scenario that A needs X and doesn't work with Y; B needs Y and doesn't work with X.

All you then need to do is write a few lines of code to map between the two similar models (or use libraries that do exactly that, like AutoMapper).

Comment: How can JIL ignore method property inside object?

Comment: @IamStalker any of `[IgnoreDataMember]`, `[JilDirective(...)]` and `ShouldSerializeXXX()` - see [readme.md](https://github.com/kevin-montrose/Jil/blob/master/README.md)

Comment: It handles only property that aren't methods look at my api
`interface IFoo {  int GetFoo(int x); int X {get;set;} }`
I want only x as json

Comment: @IamStalker you should only see `X` there - methods like `GetFoo` are ignored. What  are you seeing?

Comment: `Error occurred building a deserializer for IWFGraph: Expected a parameterless constructor for IWFGraph`,